# Time zone Conversion in SQL UTC to IST

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert datetime column from UTC to IST. When I try doing that, I am getting wrong conversion. Instead of +5:30 hours, this statement just added +2:00 hours.

```
select convert_timezone('UTC','IST',('2019-12-04 12:00:00'))
```

output

```
2019-12-04 14:00:00.0
```

Can someone help me here!

Comment: Yes. I am using Amazon Redshift

Comment: Is IST available? `select pg_timezone_names();`, `select pg_timezone_abbrevs();`

Comment: Based on this info: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ IST is not unique abreviation of timezone. I guess in this case it assumes Israel Standard Time. see this list or redshift timezones: select  pg_timezone_abbrevs()

Comment: Thanks @EdgarsT. . I used 'Asia/Kolkata' and it worked

Comment: @EdgarsT. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer as comment solved problem:
Based on this info: [timeanddate.com/time/zones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) IST is not unique abbreviation of timezone. I guess in this case it assumes Israel Standard Time. Run this code to see full list or AWS Redshift timezones: `select pg_timezone_names();` or for abbreviations: `select pg_timezone_abbrevs();`